# Revolute articulation body has different rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ros

I am trying to make robot turns using articulation body with revolute type. Everything would be fine, but provided that my wheels are configured the same way, they rotate differently, to be more precise, one wheel turns by 10 degrees, and the other by 15 and I don't know what the problem is, I don't think the problem is in the errors of physics calculations, since the size is too big for this. Also, make no mistake, I give the wheels the same force to rotate, literally, all the parameters are the same, but in the end I get different wheel behavior.
Can someone tell me what the problem is here?
The same settings
[image]
The same forces for rotation
[image]

Here code for rotation:

```
private void RobotRotationInput(float rotSpeed) // m/s and rad/s
        {
            if (rotSpeed > maxRotationalSpeed)
            {
                rotSpeed = maxRotationalSpeed;
            }
            
            var wheelRotation = (rotSpeed / wheelRadius);
            var wheelSpeedDiff = ((rotSpeed * trackWidth) / wheelRadius);
            
            if (rotSpeed != 0)
            {
                wheelRotation = (wheelRotation - (wheelSpeedDiff / 1)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            }
            else
            {
                wheelRotation *= Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            }

            var rotationOffset = (wheelRotation - rotationWheel1.xDrive.targetVelocity) / 4;
            wheelRotation -= rotationOffset;
            
            SetSpeed(rotationWheel1, wheelRotation);
            SetSpeed(rotationWheel2, wheelRotation);
            SetSpeed(rotationWheel3, wheelRotation);
            SetSpeed(rotationWheel4, wheelRotation);
        }
```